# How to Display Rss Feed In Windows Phone My APP?Not in Browser

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webview, rss

I am New to Windows Phone i  Follows [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487167%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) And Developed a Application

Using this I have Successfully integrated My application But Here The Problem is that When i on click it opens in the Mobile Browser

Over there its

```
if (sItem.Links.Count > 0)
    {
        // Get the associated URI of the feed item.
        Uri uri = sItem.Links.FirstOrDefault().Uri;

        // Create a new WebBrowserTask Launcher to navigate to the feed item. 
        // An alternative solution would be to use a WebBrowser control, but WebBrowserTask is simpler to use. 
        WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
        webBrowserTask.Uri = uri;
        webBrowserTask.Show();
    }
```

But i want to Open the data in My App itself.. I mean Without any other Web-browsers it should Load In my Application.. Can any one Suggest me..

Here I every thing should process at Back ground and open in my Application itself not in any other browser...

like this...

[image]

Comment: Assuming sItem is a SyndicationItem you can get the text or html from sItem.Content and display in a TextBlock or Web browser control on another page. Bear in mind that most sites would only syndicate a summary of the full article content.

Comment: I dont Want to Use Web Browser In android We have Web View.. What will be in that place..

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the `WebBrowser` class not the `WebBrowserTask`.

For instance, if you want to show `http://mywebsite.com` in a `WebBrowser` control inside your app, you'd do the following:

```
myWebBrowser.NavigateTo(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com,UriKind.Absolute));
```

Of course, this suppose that you already have an instance of the `WebBrowser` Class defined in your view. If not, you can do it via the `XAML` this way:

```
<WebBrowser Name="myWebBrowser" Width="200" Heigth="200"/>
```

Comment: hi.. user@PiRhAnAs Here I dont want to Use any browser i want to use my app as a Rss feed app so that when i click on any link it should display there.. only...

Comment: did you try this code? It will show rss feed in your app

Comment: this will not open the phon's web browser, but it will show the links inside the app. What I did is exactly equivalent to the WebView in Android, if that's what you want.